# Handling null values from database in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

This works fine:

```
@Repository
public interface VoteDao extends CrudRepository <Vote, Long> {

@Query(value = "select sum(points) from votes where siteuserid= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
int countBySiteUser(@Param("user") SiteUser user);
}
```

Except in case when there are no votes yet that the result is NULL and the problem is that I do not know how to handle that case of checking when it is Null since the query does no return anything when I ask...

```
    System.out.println("!!!!: PROPOSAL VoteService: " + voteDao.countBySiteUser(user));
```

Should it print a Null value for that sysout? The DAO is supposed to answer with a NULL value, but it is not. I would be able to handle that NULL if provided, but it does not.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Unanswerable. What is your application *supposed* to do? Ask the designer. Ask a colleague. We can't tell you.

Comment: kagmole understood and solved the question clearly. Why do you need to know what is it for? How is that gonna help

Comment: @Mike What EJP is telling you is "what do you want instead of null"? In my answer I just assumed that you wanted 0, but it could have not be the case.

Comment: @Kagmole I did not say that I do not want a NULL. I said I did not know how to handle it. I do not understand him. Thanks Kagmole

Comment: @Mike Well that's the point. How you will handle it is up to you (or your designer, your colleague, this is what he meant). Anyway, glad my suggestion satisfies your need. ;)

Comment: kagmole I see @EJP has a lot of karma so I wanted to understand his point to make better future questions useful for other people. Sorry, stackoverflow is great for learning, but rookies need help even with questioning... I appreciate your empathy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` to handle `null` as `0`, which correspond to what you actually mean.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(points), 0) FROM votes WHERE siteuserid = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
int countBySiteUser(@Param("user") SiteUser user);
```

... or another solution with a programmatic approach:

```
// Integer instead of int to add the "null" handling
@Query(
    value = "SELECT SUM(points) FROM votes WHERE siteuserid = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
Integer countBySiteUser(@Param("user") SiteUser user);
```

Usage:

```
Integer count = voteDao.countBySiteUser(user);

if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}

System.out.println("!!!!: PROPOSAL VoteService: " + count);
```

The `COALESCE` solution seems better to me. But as [@EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819683/handling-null-values-from-database-in-spring-jpa/43819745#comment74677809_43819683) said, it will depend on your needs.

Comment: The first approach works fine,  but the explanation in the doc is not really clear...[link]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce  Can you explain it? Thanks

Comment: It will return the first non-null occurrence in its arguments.
If `SUM(points)` returns null, it will try the next argument, which is `0`.
If `SUM(points)` returns an value, it will return the actual value without testing the next arguments.

Comment: thank you very much. I think this will help other (not programmers, like me) to clarify that it works like an if.